# How safe is it to leave my passport in my hotel room?

Tags: passports, legal, safety, hotels

How sure can I be that a passport left in my hotel room is safe? On my trip, I don't need to carry it around with me every day, so would like to leave it behind.

Comment: What country? Some countries require aliens to carry actual documentation with them and show it on demand by law enforcement etc.

Comment: In some places hotel thieves are common and passports very much liked by them.

Comment: I mean places like New York or London.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan don't countries have databases in which they can check entry of a certain individual in the country only by passport number?

Comment: @Willeke do you mean that hotel workers are also thieves? Or do you mean that any stranger can enter at a hotel room without being noticed?

Comment: @user Countries can make regulations regardless of what databases they have.

Comment: Ah ok, because one can fear to lose it and so they leave it at the hotel.

Comment: @user, it can be staff, it can be fellow guests but it is more likely people who get in when they know they can break into the rooms (or use the open doors when cleaning is going on.)

Comment: And it is not a certain class of hotels, it happens in the cheaper ones but also in the top range (and all in between) as it sometimes makes the news when someone famous mentioned jewelry being stolen out of their hotel.

Comment: Ok, but consider the passport is supposedly locked in a safe, so a restricted people know the code (the passport holder and the worker). So the chances maybe are little.

Comment: @user see my answer, I disagree - I was able to get into one without the pin, incredibly easily.

Comment: Regulations may also predate databases.  Governments don't have much incentive to reduce requirements on foreign visitors unless it saves the government money (which this wouldn't; an alternative might)

Comment: Frankly, I'd be much more worried about losing my passport or being pickpocketed out and about than leaving it in a decent hotel room.

Comment: Yeah, at the end of the day what's the interest in stealing a passport to a simple layman?

Comment: @user New York and London are two very different cities in very different countries so that perhaps wasn't the best example. Could you answer Patricia's query with an explanation rather than by example?

Comment: I generally leave my passport at reception, in their safe. I feel that there is more accountability that way

Answer (score 57):

Safes are only as secure as the users who have access.

This could be you (the guest), a presumably trusted manager, or someone with access to the room and some google-fu.

Story: I had my honeymoon in Fiji. My wife locked our stuff in the safe, and it included something we needed at the time....medicine maybe? Point is, she forgot the PIN, or it no longer worked at least, we won't say who was wrong ;)

5 minutes of Google searching, I found there's a default override PIN for that particular safe that most hotels don't change, and indeed, was able to use it to unlock our safe, get the stuff out, AND set a new PIN!

(At the end of our stay I asked to speak to the owner who we'd gotten to know, and let him know what happened. He was going to change the default PINs).

Comment: Richard Feynman had a similar story with safes

Comment: `He was going to change the default PINs` I wouldn't be surprised if you go back there a year later and it still works.

Answer (score 9):

There are various factors to consider here, in my view. The questions to ask here are:

1. How likely is it that you get pickpocketed? This depends on many individual factors. How alert are you usually? Do you get distracted? Have you been pickpocketed in the past? Do you look like an easy mark, for instance because you cannot fight back or run after the thief? Do you keep your passport in your back pocket?
2. How likely is it that you get stopped by the police? One of the factors is "how suspicious do you look?". (Yes, I know that's not how it should be in an ideal world, but this is how real life works unfortunately.)
3. How likely is it that your passport gets stolen from your hotel room? In general, you can get some information on how safe a city is by looking on guidebooks or on the internet. Otherwise, you can trust your instinct: does the hotel look safe? Is the reception always staffed? How easy is it to get inside without being stopped? In your room, do you leave your passport visible on a table, or hidden in a side internal pocket of your suitcase? is there a room safe?
   Note that hotels tend to hide all bad publicity, so I don't think you will get an honest answer from them if you just ask "how safe is this place". Personally I never had troubles with hotel thieves, so instinctively I tend to underestimate this risk, but people with different experience would probably warn me that it is a mistake.
4. Do you have another form of ID, such as a driving license? Even a foreign one. What would happen to you if police stops you? This is location-dependent. This never happened to me, but in most countries I guess that in practice nothing will happen in the typical case (if you have a foreign ID), and the worst case is that you get scolded, you spend a few hours in a police station, and then they call your embassy or accompany you back to your hotel to retrieve your passport. Again, one of the factors is "how suspicious do you look?"
5. What would happen to you if your passport gets stolen? If you don't have another valid form of ID to continue your travel, it is basically guaranteed that you will be denied boarding or entry into your next destination, and you will need a trip to the embassy. At the very best, you will only need to get a new passport when you arrive home, which is a mild annoyance.

This is very location-dependent, but all things considered in my view 3 is the worst annoyance. I feel safer leaving my passport in my hotel if I don't have another form of ID to continue my trip, and otherwise carry it with me. Your mileage may vary, though. It is a personal choice, and opinions differ.

Comment: I have always chosen to keep my passport with me, (unless going swimming,) in an under clothing pouch, as more safe than leaving it in a hotel room. (And I do not trust those safes there at all.)

Comment: Considering all comments here, what if I let my passport in a suitcase that is provided with a number-lock system? How can potential staff aiming to steal know that my passport is there in the first place?

Comment: @user If your room safe is locked, to a potential thief that's already a strong hint that it contains *something* worth stealing.

Comment: @user, hotel thieves who are not staff seem more common than stealing staff.

Answer (score 6):

In New York, you are not required to carry ID, and you don't have to show ID to a police officer as mentioned in [this article](https://www.nyclu.org/en/publications/column-showing-id-nypd-our-times) and several others.

For London, you can view our guide here:

- [Should I carry a passport around everywhere I go in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/should-i-carry-a-passport-around-everywhere-i-go-in-the-uk)

> The UK is not like Russia or Uzbekistan where police on the street can and do stop you without cause and demand ID

Comment: Given my attitude, I better don't go to NYC then

Comment: Actually there is a US federal law which requires most aliens in the US to carry with them any "alien registration receipt" which they've been issued. For a tourist, this is either the entry stamp in the passport or the I-94 form. The law is not enforced by the NYPD, and the chance of running into federal immigration officers in New York is infinitesimally small. Even then, the law is not typically enforced by federal immigration officers, but they do mention it frequently. Concerned tourists can comply with the law by printing and carrying a copy of the [I-94 form](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov).

Comment: At least technically, all of NYC and and most of the "edge" of the country (including the entire state I live in) is within the 100 mile "border" zone in which US Customs and Border Patrol have expanded "rights" to stop, search and seize. Given the current climate, it might be best to take your passport with you. See https://www.citylab.com/equity/2018/05/who-lives-in-border-patrols-100-mile-zone-probably-you-mapped/558275/.

Comment: @user curious, why do you say that?

Comment: @jcm well I'm the type of person who doesn't like his rights to be frowned upon, even if I can do without just for the sake of respecting the authority of the individual I may find in front of me. For example, if I technically have the right not to show a certain paper, I won't show that paper even if I have it, otherwise rights would be meaningless in the first place. That's how I am. So yeah, I might risk to get killed by a cop in the U.S with my attitude and stubbornness.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes, Border Patrol could start operating in New York City under current law, but they don't.  ICE does, but they don't conduct patrols or checkpoints.  Tourists are exceedingly unlikely to get caught up in an ICE raid, and if they do they are exceedingly unlikely to face charges for failing to have their passports on hand.

Comment: @user the NYPD isn't going to bother you.  They won't demand ID unless you are suspected of a crime, and they don't enforce immigration law so they won't care whether you have your passport or I-94 form with you.

Comment: @phoog https://www.chalkbeat.org/posts/ny/2019/03/07/customs-and-border-protection-trucks-outside-of-a-washington-heights-school-set-a-community-on-edge/ sure CBP operates in NYC, certainly at the airport and elsewhere accord to that article.  Also https://twitter.com/cbpnewyorkcity?lang=en

Comment: The airport is another thing, of course I have to show my passport.

Comment: Half of Indiana and Illinois add a corner of Nevada is inside the 100 mile zone because ships are allowed to sail all the way to Chicago and Stockton without going through a border control point.

Comment: @DavePhD CBP field officers in airports are distinct from Border Patrol, which is a separate service within CBP. CBP field officers do not conduct patrols or internal immigration enforcement of any kind. (The *P* in CBP stands for "protection," by the way, not "patrol.")  Border Patrol officers wear green uniforms and their vehicles have green stripes, not blue, and they do not operate in NYC.  I don't know what those vehicles were doing at that school, but it is certainly nothing that would lead to trouble for a tourist.  Perhaps they were showing off the dog at an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Some hotels have cabinets (or safes) which can be locked with a padlock. For best security (you never know who has a key) you could bring your own padlock.

Comment: These are more common in hostels.